# Gradient of angle function on sphere has norm 1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In Ballmann's book, it is shown that the internal distance $d(x, y)$ on the unit sphere $S$ in $\mathbb R^{m+1}$ (that is the infimum of lengths of curves on $S$ from $x$ to $y$) is given by the angle from $x$ to $y$.

The proof goes as follows. For a given $x ∈ S$, let $φ(y)$ denote the angle from $x$ to $y$. The idea is to show that $\lVert \operatorname{grad}φ(y) \rVert =1$. From that point on I know how to proceed.

This is the tricky bit. 
We can write points $y ∈ S \smallsetminus \{±x\}$
uniquely as
$$
y = \cos(φ)x + \sin(φ)z
$$
with $z = z(y)$ in the equator of $x$, that is $x⋅z = 0$, $\lVert z \rVert =1$, and $φ = φ(y) ∈ (0, π)$. The
function $φ \colon  S \smallsetminus \{±x\} \to (0, π)$ is smooth, with gradient
$$
(\operatorname{grad} φ)(\cos(φ)x + \sin(φ)z) = -\sin(φ)x + \cos(φ)z.
$$

I'm not really sure why $φ$ is smooth and I really can't see how the gradient is computed.

*Edit.* This is what I thought was done here. If we write $g(φ,z) := \cos(φ)x + \sin(φ)z$, then $g(φ(y),z(y)) = y$. Differentiating both sides and applying the chain rule should yield the desired result, but I don't think it does.

Comment: Hi! Do you know the implicit function theorem and the chain rule? It shoud be straightforward applications of those!

Comment: @Carot, I think that's what the author had in mind, but still it's not straightforward to me...

Comment: Ok you have basically 2 options depending on how you want to define smoth on $S$. You can say it is locally the restriction of a smooth function on $R^{m+1}$ using the implicit function theorem, compute the gradient there and voilà or use charts as in differential geometry. Those two definitions should be equivalent. I don't know what your level in differential geometry is so I can't know what level of detail you want...

Comment: @Carot, thanks for the reply. I've added some context in the question. The problem is really how the chain rule is applied: on which functions?